# Checking 2 dates with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to check if arrivedate is the same as leavedate then it should show an alert box saying "Please change arrivedate".

Why isn't it working in JavaScript.

```
Leaving: <input type='date' id='mydateL' class="icon"></input>
Returning: <input type='date' id='mydateR' class="icon"></input>
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="datetimevalidation()"


<script>

function datetimevalidation() {

    var leavedate = new Date(document.getElementById("mydateL").value);
    var arrivedate = new Date(document.getElementById("mydateR").value);      

    if(leavedate == arrivedate) {        
         alert('Please change arrivedate.');
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: where have you assigned `datetimevalidation`

Comment: Why don't you go the classic way and change the dates into milliseconds?

Comment: What is the value returned by `document.getElementById("mydateL").value`? Parsing strings with the Date constructor is strongly advised against, there's a good chance that both *leavedate* and *arrivedate* are *NaN* in some or all browsers.

Comment: @RobG this is to get the date the user selects?

Comment: Input type date isn't supported by all browsers, so what is the value?

Comment: @RobG what about a datepicker? is that a better way to do it?

Comment: "Why isn't it working" isn't a reasonable question. What input did you try? What was the result? What error do you see? What browser(s) are you using?

Comment: @RobG I tried the same dates. then pressed the button to see if it works. but nothing happens. in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just convert the dates into longs for comparison.

```
 var leavedate = +new Date(document.getElementById("mydateL").value);
 var arrivedate = +new Date(document.getElementById("mydateR").value);


    if(leavedate == arrivedate) {        
         alert('Please change arrivedate.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `getFullYear()`, `getMonth()` and `getDate()` in you `if` condition.

```html
Leaving:
<input type='date' id='mydateL' class="icon"></input>Returning:
<input type='date' id='mydateR' class="icon"></input>
<div onclick="datetimevalidation()">Click Me</div>
<script>
    function datetimevalidation() {

        var leavedate = new Date(document.getElementById("mydateL").value);
        var arrivedate = new Date(document.getElementById("mydateR").value);

        if (leavedate.getFullYear() == arrivedate.getFullYear() && leavedate.getMonth() == arrivedate.getMonth() && leavedate.getDate() == arrivedate.getDate()) {
            document.write('Please change arrivedate.');
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: That isn't required at all. If they are valid date objects set to the same time on the same date, then the Dates can be compared directly, e.g. `+date0 == +date1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Leaving: <input type='date' id='mydateL' class="icon"></input>
Returning: <input type='date' id='mydateR' class="icon"></input>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Try to convert the date object and the comparison will work :

```
 function myFunction() 
    {

      var leavedate = new Date(document.getElementById("mydateL").value);

      leavedate = leavedate+ "";

      var arrivedate = new Date(document.getElementById("mydateR").value); 

      arrivedate = arrivedate+ ""; 


      if(leavedate == arrivedate) 
        {        
             alert('Please change arrivedate.');
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied sufficient information to answer the question precisely, so only general advice can be given.

Input type date isn't supported by all browsers in use, so simply converting whatever the user inputs to a date object without first validating the input will not be a robust solution.

Consider a British user with settings for dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy who enters 23/11/2015. This value is then parsed using the Date constructor.

In Chrome (which supports date inputs), the input will provide a hint of dd/mm/yyyy based on system settings. The value returned by the input's *value* property will be a string of 2015-11-23, which will be parsed by the Date constructor in Chrome as a local date.

In Firefox v42, which doesn't support Date inputs, the string will be returned exactly as entered by the user. Firefox will parse 23/11/2015 as if it was mm/dd/yyyy and return a date for 11/11/2016.

Safari 9 also doesn't support date inputs and will try to parse it as mm/dd/yyyy like Firefox, but will return an invalid date (since there is no month 23).

Omniweb 6 acts like Safari.

So the statement that "it doesn't work" is not surprising. For a robust date input, you will have to:

1. Specify the format that users should enter
2. Validate that the value entered is a valid date
3. Compare the values

If valid strings are entered, they can be compared for equality directly, there is no need to convert them to Date objects. However, if date objects are required later, there's no harm in comparing dates if they are converted to numbers, e.g.

```
if (+date0 == + date1) {
  // Dates are equal
}
```

The dates must be converted to number first as otherwise `==` will compare them as objects, and no two objects are ever equal so the result will always be false unless *d0* and *d1* reference the same date object (which, given comments on the OP, seems to be the problem, in Chrome at least).